# SQL query to generate report on the basis of parameter selection

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement in which on the basis of the options selected by the user, a report gets generated.

The options are as follows:

**Mandatory fields:**

Org:

Start Date:

End Date:

**Select one option (Radio Button):**

Event date

Finalized Date

On the basis of the option selected my report should generate accordingly
So far the code is:

```
`DECLARE @Org           VARCHAR(50)         
 DECLARE @UserName      VARCHAR(50)          
 DECLARE @StartDate     DATETIME            
 DECLARE @EndDate       DATETIME    
 DECLARE @FinalizedDate DateTime 
 DECLARE @EventDate     DateTime 

SET @org = ‘zzz’
SET @StartDate = '2014-08-29'
SET @EndDate = '2014-09-30'

Select A.*, EventDate, FinalizedDate, Org
From ABC A
WHERE   Org = @Org AND (@EventDate  BETWEEN @StartDate  AND @EndDate AND @EventDate IS NOT NULL) 
    or (@FinalizedDate   BETWEEN @StartDate  AND @EndDate AND @FinalizedDate  IS NOT NULL)
```

> Please note that this is just the sample code the actual code is much more complicated.

I need to create a stored proc to use it in SSRS report. When I run this code, it doesn't return any data.

Comment: Upon further reflection,. this query makes no sense at all.  Why would you check if the passed in `@eventdate` is within the passed in start and end dates?  Shouldn't you be testing start and end date against the eventdate in the table?

Comment: Also in a comment on sqluser's answer you mention that *"user only gets to enter date for `@StartDate` and `@EndDate`. and they get to select whether they want to see the data of EventDate or FinalizedDate. "*  What are the ACTUAL parameters being passed?

Comment: I am trying to understand and convert ColdFusion code to SQL/SSRS. Your question triggered me to check the ColdFusion code and from what I see I feel there is no parameter passed. here's the code `<INPUT TYPE = "Radio" NAME="DateOpt" VALUE = "EVENTDATE" CHECKED CLASS = "formbutton"> Event Date <BR>` , `<INPUT TYPE = "Radio" NAME="DateOpt" VALUE = "FinalizedDate" CHECKED CLASS = "formbutton"> Finalized Date <BR>`

Comment: Ok.  So the parameter name should be DateOpt, as a varchar(20).  I'll change my answer again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

My prior answer is wrong because it was based on a misreading of your *Select one* section.

First off, the following is wrong:

```
 DECLARE @FinalizedDate DateTime 
 DECLARE @EventDate     DateTime
```

Your code shouldn't pass those as separate datetimes.  It should pass the selection as a single value indicating whether they want to test the Finalized or Event date.  So, something like this:

```
DECLARE @DateOpt varchar(20)
```

Where DateOp will contain "EventDate" or "FinalizedDate"

This means your `where` clause is going to look like this:

```
WHERE  (Org = @Org)
AND (

( (@DateOpt ='EVENTDATE') AND (EventDate BETWEEN @StartDate  AND @EndDate) )
OR
( (@DateOpt ='FinalizedDate') AND (FinalizedDate BETWEEN @StartDate  AND @EndDate) )

)
```

Comment: I need to pass the value to the EventDate and FinalizedDate from the query itself. how do I do that? Or else can I get rid of both these parameters? Is it really required?

Comment: This is started to make sense to me now...I am so excited to try this option  which I can only do tomorrow as I don't have connectivity to the server. I am only stuck at this point though  _"Where Searchtype is going to be a 0 for EventDate and 1 for FinalizedDate"_ why is that so?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ISNULL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) function to include or exclude your optional parametres in your `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT A.*, EventDate, FinalizedDate, Org
FROM ABC A
WHERE Org = @Org
AND (@EventDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) 
OR (@FinalizedDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
AND EventDate = ISNULL(@EventDate, EventDate)
AND FinalizedDate = ISNULL(@FinalizedDate , FinalizedDate)
```

For better performance as it's better to not use functions in `WHERE` clause, there are some other alternatives like `CASE` or `UNION` to achieve this.

Comment: I will try this option tomorrow since I don't have the connectivity now and will update you if it works. I am still not sure of how the value passes to the parameters: `@EventDate` and `@FinalizedDate`. Because the user only gets to enter date for `@StartDate` and `@EndDate`. and they get to select whether they want to see the data of EventDate or FinalizedDate.

Comment: If you want to make `@EventDate` and `@FinalizedDate` optional in your proc, you need to assign a value to them when your declaring. Better to assign `NULL` value. Something like: `DECLARE @FinalizedDate DateTime = NULL` and 
 `DECLARE @EventDate  DateTime = NULL`

Comment: This still won't return valid results.  If `@finalizeddate` is within the date range, it will pull for ALL orgs....